Apache CXF Runtime WS Security migration issue in karaf
We are trying to upgrade the Apache CXF Runtime WS Security version. when i am deploying there is an issue with the osgi.wiring.package : org.opensaml.saml.common. we have the below jars available in karaf still facing the issue in library versions.

karaf@root()> start 74
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
Error starting bundle 74: Unable to resolve org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-security 74: missing requirement [org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-security 74] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.opensaml.saml.common)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-security 74] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.opensaml.saml.common)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))]
opensaml-*4.3.0 jars already available as shown in screen shot
we tried to deploy the all the opensaml* jars and cxf-rt-ws-security bundle is not active.

As shown in screen shot package is already available but still looking for same package. Please help me to identify the issue and solution

Maybe the problem is, that the package "org.opensaml.saml.common" has only the version "0.0.0"
